# Display errors set to none still shows warnings

Tags: error-reporting

When I set my Joomla config "Error reporting" to "none", I'm still seeing a PHP warning on the front of the site. However, when I set Error reporting" to "System Default" that warning is suppressed.

My php.ini is configured so that display errors is `off` and error reporting is `32759`.  This is the sum of the bitmask values of the following error function constants:

> E_USER_DEPRECATED         16384
>   E_DEPRECATED               8192
>   E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR        4096
>   E_STRICT                   2048
>   E_USER_NOTICE              1024
>   E_USER_WARNING              512
>   E_USER_ERROR                256
>   E_COMPILE_WARNING           128
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR              64
>   E_CORE_WARNING               32
>   E_CORE_ERROR                 16
>   E_PARSE                       4
>   E_WARNING                     2
>   E_ERROR                       1

The warning in question is:

> "Failed loading XML file, failed to load external entity" using SimpleXML to load a remote XML feed which no longer exists.

Why is Joomla's "Error reporting" to "none" still allowing this warning to be displayed on the front of the site?

Comment: Let's not hide a rash with a turtleneck sweater, let's medicate that sucker!  Please show us the cause of the issue so that we can help you fix it up properly.

Comment: Why did you leave out `E_NOTICE` ?  Did you actually want to see that one?  [32767](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) covers all of the bases.  Can you show us the actual line of code from php.ini just so we can double check for you?

Comment: You are loading an RSS/XML feed using Simple XML.  Please could you supply the XML feed in question.  It's saying it doesn't exist so that's another problem you could resolve.

I would suggest you consider the server/host as the potential  
problem.  Just because you have set display errors to none the server setup may not allow it.  But that would still be confusing as system default suppresses it.